# How to catch duplicate values ​bringing columns without group by in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

[image: example]

I tried using row_number() but it didn't work, just return the row count

A example there is in the first print

[image]

Comment: Look at *dense_rank*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that helps.

```
SELECT val, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY val) my_rank 
FROM t;
```